# win10 utility file copy multiple directories from search result

Tags: windows-10, file-management

My computer has been infested with a redirect a string in 100s of files. Using file locator string search shows many many directories with files in various path.
I intend to move these invested files - ***using copy-all inside the search result window*** -  to an empty external hard disk with the full structure intact, except the drive letter.
If after this process the computer screams "file not found / missing" I know where to look and eliminate the redirect part - I hope, then place the cleaned file to the needed location on C: .
At a later date I intend to erase the external data.

The following information should help to avoid duplication of ideas what else to do, I did:

Browser: Clear cache, history. Install No Redirect extension to FF 83.0. Add cybercriminal's internet address to Win10 HOSTS.
TOOLS: CCleaner, Search & Destroy (not used $$$), Malwarebytes, MS Defender.

SYSTEM: sfc /verifyonly , Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth , Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth , DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth (error free)

Answer (score 0):

No useful answer from any internet source / forum for 2 or 3 weeks.
Searched for strings in Hexeditor to see what sort of trouble was hiding.
Did file search with strings found in Hexeditor.
Zipped found files, #>100
Deleted files with string in Search.
Later: Deleted *.ZIP as no errors showed up.